# Intellij+Springboot+Thymeleaf+gradle - autoreload html resources

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using IntelliJ Ultimate, Spring Boot, and Thymeleaf.

I want to enable auto-reload of HTML without restarting the server and without CTRL-F9.

I have read the following already and I think it should be working, but it's not:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34
- [IntelliJ 15, SpringBoot devtools livereload not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869606/intellij-15-springboot-devtools-livereload-not-working)
- [Livereload for assets in Intellij using Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104664/livereload-for-assets-in-intellij-using-spring-boot/37769756#comment73860827_37769756)

I have done the following steps:

**build.gradle snippet**

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure', version: '1.5.2.RELEASE'
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

bootRun {
    addResources = true
}
```

IntelliJ Settings for Compilier:

[image: Intellij Compilier]

And Intellij Registry Setting:

[image: Intelij Registry]

My HTML is in `main\resources\templates` and my `application.properties` is in `\resources\`

I then have tried both running and debugging the project but either way, I still have to rebuild (CTRL-F9) between changes to the HTML.

Reading [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34) from snicoll and dsayer this should be possible without the CTRL-F9:

Comment: Followed everything here and still doesn't work. Restart an all.

* Spring Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE
* IntelliJ 2018.3.4

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It appears after adding the registry setting :

```
compilier.automake.allow.when.app.running
```

You need to restart not only the Springboot server but Intellij too.

It is going now.

Comment: great job @douggreaney

Answer (score 0):

If you are still struggling with `spring-boot-devtools`, I recommend using Gulp to automate templates and resources reload. Following is a little Gulp task that does the magic for me:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'), 
watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    return watch('src/main/resources/**/*.*', () => {
        gulp.src('src/main/resources/**')
            //replace with build/resources/main/ for netBeans
            .pipe(gulp.dest('out/production/resources/')); 
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

I also wrote a short [blog post](https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-boot-auto-reload-thymeleaf-templates/) on this topic which includes other methods as well.