# SpringBoot livereload has no effect on OS X for static sources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, livereload

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.4.RELEASE with embedded Tomcat server and Intellij Idea 2018.2 on my Os X High Sierra.

As tutorial says

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html

I added in my pom.xml following dependency

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And after that I see

> [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       :
>   LiveReload server is running on port 35729

wher server starts.

But anyway changes in static sources has no effect, and I have to press Cmd+F9 to see that in the browser.

I tried all tips from [IntelliJ 15, SpringBoot devtools livereload not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869606/intellij-15-springboot-devtools-livereload-not-working)

like turning on 'Build project programmatically' or 'compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running', but nothing helps.

My static sources (angularjs templates an files) living at

> src > main > resources > static > templates

may be location for static is wrong?

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: Have you made sure you're doing a purge/reload for your browser cache?

Comment: @Dovmo what do you mean?

Comment: When you open Chrome `DevTools` you can click and hold the browser refresh button and click `Empty Cache and Hard Reload`. You can also select the option in DevTools for [`Disable Cache`](https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-how-to-completely-disable-cache) to turn it off. It will force-reload those static resources when you revisit the page

Comment: @Dovmo exact reason why I want to use live reload is not to use 'clean cache' :) I also use Playframework on another project, and there live reload works smooth as baby bottom, without cleaning cache in browser. But not with Spring :/

Comment: Arkady, sure that's fair, but reporting on whether doing a hard-refresh / Disable Cache on your browser resolves the issue could be helpful in debugging the root cause of the issue

Comment: When the 'devtools' dependency is present, LiveReaload is automatically enabled. In case, it is disabled in any of the configuration properties files, you can enable it adding the line `spring.devtools.livereload.enabled=true`

Comment: @Johna I've tried to add this option. Unfortunately, it has no effect..

Answer (score 0):

Put the static at the same level as src as a "resources" folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a misunderstanding here.

Among other things, the spring dev-tools offer you [Automatic Restart](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart) (which is going to restart the server completely when there is a change in the classpath, excluding the static resources) and [Live Reload](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-livereload) (reload the browser when there is a change in the static resources).

With that being said, the Live Reload feature has two details that you need to keep in mind:

1. You also need to install and use a browser extension like: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei
2. You can only have one server with live reload at the time (Otherwise, only the first one will be used).

With this configuration, a change in a static file should trigger the browser reload. If the change in the file is not enough, try building the project without stop it.

> In Eclipse, saving a modified file causes the classpath to be updated and triggers a restart. In IntelliJ IDEA, building the project (Build -> Build Project) has the same effect.