# Spring Boot Devtools not working in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use devtools in a Spring Boot project on IntelliJ. I was expecting the app to be automatically updated when I edit and save the code, but it doesn't happen. I tried the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869606/intellij-15-springboot-devtools-livereload-not-working), but in my version of the IDE that registry option is not present (version 2012.2.1). Did they remove it or what?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was found in IntelliJ knowledge base [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4404522882450-Spring-Boot-DevTools-Live-Reload-Not-Working). Now the option is not in the registry, but in the Advanced settings tab.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: It may be hard to understand only if you haven't read the linked question. Read it and it will be perfectly clear. Also it is explained in the link in the answer.